# ol3 update layer after time change

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to refresh my ol.layer.Tile with an ol.source.TileWMS as source, but calling source.updateParams has no effects and chrome inspector tool doesn't show network activities, such as geoserver requests. So where is the trick?

I use ol v3.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by upgrading to v3.18.2

Answer (score 1):

You can using the params  with parameter STYLE

For example:

```
var params = {LAYERS: layerId, VERSION: '1.3.0', STYLES: style};
var source = layer.getSource();
source.updateParams(params);
```

Inside, style is the name of style in the geoserver